# Running a benchmark on javascript ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, benchmarking, design-patterns

One function returns a single item, for one id.
The other function returns 3 items for 3 ids I just wanted to benchmark which would be best, my preference is for the single request just for simplicity. However proof is required.

I'm using jQuery $.ajax to do the get requests. The numbers don't seem right:

- I started with **100 triples** which took **0.16s**.
- **10k triples** takes in **~17s** (I had expected **~300s**), with the backend making an Endeca request.

I've selected 20 or so **id** numbers to request  [Endeca does cache by default, but for these queries it is off]

The nub of the question is how to benchmark ajax calls. Calls are fired off, the start and end times need to be married up afterwards to get the time. However the async call flies through. To me it looks like I am just measuring a series of function calls.

Comment: Did you check the console to see if any of the requests are actually being retrieved from the browser cache?

Comment: **FACEPALM** I've been going to the effort of clearing cachies for the web pages. Of course this will get cached on repeated requests.
It doesn't appear obvious how to turn off caching on Chrome.

Comment: Just add a timestamp to the querystring of each request, then they won't be cached (because the url is different each time).

Comment: Good point.
However the intent was to make it RESTful:  
    'http://www.example-site.com/item-profile/id/456987'  
I went out of my way not to use a query string...

Comment: But it won't interfere with your url scheme. It's a client-side issue, e.g., when you use jquery's ajax and pass `cache: false`, it will append a timestamp before sending the request.

Comment: Thanks. I tried (cache: false, and async: false)  and found a few bugs, fixed the bugs then it worked. I commented out the cache, and async and it took about the same time. Up from 17sec to 490sec.

Comment: Great! One last tip: avoid async:false unless you're using it just for testing. Otherwise, the UI will freeze during the ajax call.

Comment: Naturally, the benchmarks work fine with no aync. Just clambering up the learning slope; thanks.